# c++ dynamic array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to understand how to create a dynamic array of pointers in C++. 
I understand that `new` returns a pointer to the allocated block of memory and `int*[10]` is an array of pointers to `int`. But why to you assign it to a `int**`? I'm struggling to understand that.

```
int **arr = new int*[10];
```

Comment: If `int[]` decays to `int*`, then `int*[]` would decay to `int**`.

Comment: You usually do `T *arr = new T[N];`. If `T` is `int`, then it becomes `int *arr = new int[N];`. If `T` is `int *`, then it becomes `int **arr = new int*[N];`.

Comment: Use std::vector, not new[].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion)

> 1 An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown
>   bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The
>   result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

So for example if you have an array like this

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

then in this declaration

```
int *p = a;
```

the array designator used as the initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

So in general if you have array

```
T a[N];
```

then in expressions with rare exceptions it is converted to pointer to its first element of the type `T *`.

In this declaration

```
int **arr = new int*[10];
```

the initializer is an array elements of which has the type `int *`. You can introduce a typedef or an alias declaration

```
typedef int * T;
```

or

```
using T = int *;
```

So you can write

```
T * arr = new T[10];
```

that is the pointer `arr` points to the first element of the dynamically allocated array. As the elements of the array has the type `int *` then the type of the pointer to an element of the array is `int **`.

That is the operator new returns pointer to the first element of the dynamically allocated array.

Comment: While closely related, an array to pointer conversion doesn't happen in the code in the question. The type of the new-expression is already a pointer rather than an array.

Comment: @user2079303 I described the general principle to make the understanding more clear.